# Api works only on localhost

Tags: node.js, api, express, namecheap

on my machine i get a json response when i  consume my api and eveything is working fine  , but  the weird thing is my api not giving me data when i upload it online , i am using namecheap shared hosting , this is the result i get when try to consume api

[image]

this is my index.js code

```
app.get("/project/index/login", (req, res) => {   (async () => {
    try {
      await client.login();
      res.send("Login successful!");
    } catch (err) {
      res.send("Login failed!");
    }   })(); });


app.get("/project/index/user/:id", (req, res) => {  
 const id = req.params.id;   (async () => {
    try{
      const data = await client.getInfo({ id: id })
      res.json(data.data);
    }catch(error){
      res.send(error);

    }
   

  })(); });

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on port http://localhost:${port}...`);
});
```

Comment: That's just trash in a screenshot. What does it look like in a browser? My guess: An error or some kind of Namecheap boilerplate which means it doesn't come from your application.

Comment: i think that the problem is coming from namecheap like you said  , i changed my app to heroku and now its working

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because your API server is running only on localhost. Check your API server!. You must run the API server which has a domain.